# How do I generate a list of tuples with the names of two students in each according to scores?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
names = ["Rachael","Nick","John","May"]
scores = [[100,50,50],[75,50,100],[100,100,50],[30,90,55]]
added_scores = []
tuplist = []
for score in scores:
    added_scores.append(sum(score))
    #I'm trying to add the scores to find their sum-easier than tyring to find similar scores individually
tuplist = tuple(zip(names,added_scores))
from operator import itemgetter
tuplist = sorted(tuplist,key=itemgetter(1))
#Here I wanted to sort the list of tuples based on lowest to highest score
print(added_scores)
print(tuplist)
```

> My goal is to make groups of two students based on their scores. I need students with the most similar scores grouped together, and I need to do this for all my students. I need an output of tuples, ex. [("May","Rachael"), ("Nick","John")], where these pairs of students have the most similar scores for group work (May with 175 pts, Rachael with 200, Nick with 225, and John with 250). I just need to know how to pull names from the tuples consecutively to generate a list of new tuples with two names per tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
tuplist = sorted(tuplist, key=lambda x: x[1])
names = [x[0] for x in tuplist]
pairs = tuple(zip(names[::2], names[1::2]))
```

This starts by sorting the tuples (like how you did, but without the need for another module). Then, we pull all the names back out. Finally, we pair up adjacent names by taking every second name starting at the first and every second starting at the second.

Edit: Here is a cleaner solution (full code):

```
names = ["Rachael","Nick","John","May"]
scores = [[100,50,50],[75,50,100],[100,100,50],[30,90,55]]
added_scores = [sum(x) for x in scores]
sortednames = [x for y,x in sorted(zip(added_scores, names))]
pairs = tuple(zip(sortednames[::2], sortednames[1::2]))
```